# How to segregate data from each other with same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got 2 tables in my database the first table is

leader

```
id   | name  | age
1    | John  | 40
2    | Doe   | 35
```

member

```
id   | name   | age
1    | Mark   | 40
2    | Jessica| 35
2    | Tiff   | 31
```

And what I want is like this

```
Group 1

Leader : John  40
Member : Mark  40

Group 2

Leader : Doe  35
Member : Jessica 35
         Tiff   31
```

My query

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, age
    FROM leader
    UNION
    SELECT id, name, age, 
    FROM member
) x
ORDER BY id
```

I've tried using UNION and JOIN but it's not working. Can someone help me, and form of help will very much appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: post your query too...

Comment: Never store age. People tend to become older each year, and your data will soon be invalid. Store date of birth instead. You can create a view that calculates the current age, or have a computed column.

Comment: You should have only one table, for all persons. Add a leaderid column (foreign key).

Comment: @Mark . . . You should be doing that at the application level.  SQL is concerned with tables, and your result set is not in a tabular format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` like this:

```
select t.col
from (
  select 0 type, id, concat('Group ', id) col
  from leader
  union all
  select 1, id, concat('Leader: ', name, ' ', age) 
  from leader
  union all
  select 2, id, concat('Member: ', name, ' ', age) 
  from member
) t
order by t.id, t.type
```

Results:

```
> | col                |
> | :----------------- |
> | Group 1            |
> | Leader: John 40    |
> | Member: Mark 40    |
> | Group 2            |
> | Leader: Doe 35     |
> | Member: Jessica 35 |
> | Member: Tiff 31    |
```

Or:

```
select t.col
from (
  select 0 type, id, concat('Group ', id) col
  from leader
  union all
  select 1, id, concat('Leader: ', name, ' ', age) 
  from leader
  union all
  select 2, id, concat('Member: ', group_concat(concat(name, ' ', age) separator '\n        ')) 
  from member
  group by id
) t
order by t.id, t.type
```

Results:

```
> | col                                   |
> | :------------------------------------ |
> | Group 1                               |
> | Leader: John 40                       |
> | Member: Mark 40                       |
> | Group 2                               |
> | Leader: Doe 35                        |
> | Member: Jessica 35                    |
> |         Tiff 31                       |
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0f73fa068e8b9b69545c0ddd6ce60e4d).